# How to define a Swift protocol with a getter and setter for an Objective-C NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dependency-injection, nsarray

I'm doing this for testing purposes. It helps with dependency injection.

I have an Objective-C library that I've imported into my Swift 3 project. One of the classes in the Objective-C library is defined this way:

```
@interface Auth : NSObject
@property (strong, readwrite) NSString *clientId;
@property (strong, readwrite) NSArray *scopes;
@end
```

In my Swift project, I want to define a protocol. The protocol should define 4 methods: 2 setters and 2 getters.

I want the protocol to be defined in a way so that I can reopen the Auth class in Swift with an extension and declare that Auth conforms to my protocol without putting anything in the body of the extension because the Objective-C class already conforms.

Here's my protocol:

```
protocol AuthProtocol {
    var clientID: String! { get set }
}
```

Here's the extension:

```
extension Auth: AuthProtocol {}
```

This works fine. Now I can treat Auth objects as AuthProtocols and have access to setting and getting their clientID property.

The problem arises when I try to make the protocol define the setter and getter for the scopes array. I believe `NSArray` is `Array<AnyObject>` in Swift. Here's what I tried:

```
protocol AuthProtocol {
    var clientID: String! { get set }
    var scopes: Array<AnyObject> { get set }
}
```

Now the line which reopens `Auth` for extension complains that

> Type `Auth` does not conform to protocol `AuthProtocol`

Xcode suggests a solution when I click on the error, which adds this code to the body of the exention:

```
extension Auth: AuthProtocol {
    internal var scopes: Array<AnyObject> {
        get {
            <#code#>
        }
        set {
            <#code#>
        }
    }
}
```

This code now has an error on the `internal` line:

> `scopes` used within its own type

How do I define `AuthProtocol` with a getter and setter for the `scopes` array so that this line:

```
extension Auth: AuthProtocol {}
```

Doesn't complain?

All this indicates to me that the problem has to do with the `NSArray` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Xcode to show you exactly what the protocol should be by using the "Generated Interface" command:

[image: Generated Interface Prompt]

this jumps you to the generated code:

```
open class Auth : NSObject {
    open var clientId: String!
    open var scopes: [Any]!
}
```

transform this generated class definition into the correct protocol definition:

```
protocol AuthProtocol {
    var clientId: String! { get set }
    var scopes: [Any]! { get set }
}

// doesn't complain anymore
extension Auth: AuthProtocol {}
```

Comment: That's a great tool! Wish I'd known about it earlier. Thank you. Your solution works. I am having trouble getting xcode to generate interfaces for me, though. When I click `Generated Interface`, xcode shows me this http://i.imgur.com/w8BJqdw.png and just hangs there. I am using Xcode 8.1 on Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.1. Any thought on that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: sadly the view is pretty buggy. a lot of the time you need to restart Xcode or clear derived data before it'll work.

Comment: Good enough. That worked. I'd had Xcode open since last night. You've helped a bunch. Thanks Casey!